# File not found at path when trying to copy

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to copy a file from one location to another. I'm pretty sure the location is correct, but I'm still getting the error in the title.

Here's some code:

```
$oDirectory = new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($extractFolder.'/res');
$oIterator = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator($oDirectory);
foreach($oIterator as $oFile) {
    if ($oFile->getFilename() == 'icon.png') {
        $icons[filesize($oFile->getPath().'/icon.png')] = $oFile->getPath().'/icon.png';
    }
}
asort($icons);
print_r($icons);
$icon_source = end($icons);
echo $icon_source;
$generated_icon_file = str_slug($packagename.$version).'.png';
Storage::copy($icon_source, $generated_icon_file);
```

The `print_r` returns (which means the files exist):

```
Array ( [19950] => /var/www/apk.land/storage/extracted_apks/res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/icon.png [31791] => /var/www/apk.land/storage/extracted_apks/res/drawable-xxxhdpi-v4/icon.png [6979] => /var/www/apk.land/storage/extracted_apks/res/drawable-hdpi-v4/icon.png [10954] => /var/www/apk.land/storage/extracted_apks/res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/icon.png )
```

The echo returns:

```
/var/www/apk.land/storage/extracted_apks/res/drawable-xxxhdpi-v4/icon.png
```

And the exact error is:

> File not found at path:
>   var/www/apk.land/storage/extracted_apks/res/drawable-xxxhdpi-v4/icon.png

P.S. PHP's `copy` function works just great.

I can't find the problem here.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It looks like the "var" is bleeding in as part of the beginning of the webaddress. Is that intended?

Comment: @JJFord3 What do you mean? I didn't understand :)

Comment: The path in the error is: var/www/apk.land/storage/extracted_apks/res/drawable-xxxhdpi-v4/icon.png

Should it be www/apk.land/storage/extracted_apks/res/drawable-xxxhdpi-v4/icon.png?

Comment: It's a local path, not a web address and it starts with /var/.

Comment: Kinda looks like the storage driver removes the initial slash before the path when copying, notice it says `var/www/...` in the error message and not `/var/www/...` No idea why though.

Comment: I noticed that too and I even placed one more '/' before it, but it stills shows it without one.

Comment: Its only showing file path.. nothing to verify really its exists or not.. but can you open this image from browser or something else?

Comment: Yes, I can and as I've stated in my question, I can copy it using PHP's `copy` function.

Comment: so just replacing `Storage::copy($icon_source, $generated_icon_file);` by `copy($icon_source, $generated_icon_file);` works ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, if you are using Laravel's Storage Facade and with that the underlying [Flysystem](https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem%20Flysystem) you have to know, that it is not intended to work with absolute paths like you did. The benefit of that is, that you could potentially work with different storage disks, that all have own configurations, that can be set in your config/filesystems.php file.

Assuming you did not change anythig there, the default "disk" would be local with an root of storage_path('app') ( = the path to your laravel storage folder/app )

If you want to know, why it is failing, we have to take a look at the source code you will find in the following code in the file vendor\league\flysystem\src\Filesystem.php

```
public function copy($path, $newpath)
{
    $path = Util::normalizePath($path); // <-- this will strip leading /
    $newpath = Util::normalizePath($newpath);
    $this->assertPresent($path); // this will cause the error in your case, because assertion cannot be fullfilled in case of missing leading / 
    $this->assertAbsent($newpath);

    return $this->getAdapter()->copy($path, $newpath); // calls the copy of your Adapter, assuming local in your case
}
```

So have a look, what would go on, if $this->getAdapter()->copy($path, $newpath) was called:

File (assuming local storage disk): vendor\league\flysystem\src\Adapter\Local.php

```
public function copy($path, $newpath)
{

    $location = $this->applyPathPrefix($path);
    $destination = $this->applyPathPrefix($newpath);
    $this->ensureDirectory(dirname($destination));
    return copy($location, $destination);
}
```

The line

```
$location = $this->applyPathPrefix($path);
```

will prepend the root path as defined in config/filesystems.php

'disks' => [

```
    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root'   => storage_path('app'),
    ],
```

As I can see in your code your files are are not stored in storage/app, 
so i think you have to change this to 'root' => storage_path()

So if you want to use Storage::copy() you have just to provide paths relative to that folder. And as it is hard to see, how you could achieve this, take a look at that.

```
    foreach($oIterator as $oFile) {
        if ($oFile->getFilename() == 'icon.png') {
            $icons[filesize($oFile->getPath().'/icon.png')] = $oIterator->getSubPath().'/icon.png';
        }
    }
```

There is [RecursiveDirectoryIterator::getSubPath](http://php.net/manual/en/recursivedirectoryiterator.getsubpathname.php) (Although quite undocumentated, which would return you the current subpath of your iterations. In your case relative to $extractFolder.'/res'.

Now you have to make sure you are calling

```
Storage::copy($icon_source, $generated_icon_file);
```

Where $icon_source and $generated_icon_file are relative to your defined 'root'.

Answer (score 9):

You said that the error is like this:

```
File not found at path: var/www/apk.land/storage/extracted_apks/res/drawable-xxxhdpi-v4/icon.png
```

Here error is saying it cannot find at `var/www` that means it's looking for `apk.land/var/www` whereas your file is located somewhere at `/var/www`. A quick fix to this can be use `file` protocol. Just use it like:

```
file:///var/www/storage/apk.land/storage/extracted_apks/res/drawable-xxxhdpi-v4/icon.png
```

Answer (score 6):

Try with `File::copy($file, $dest)` instead `of Storage::copy($old, $new)`
`File::copy()` is the wrapper on **PHP's** `copy()` function

Answer (score 3):

Insert `/` before `var/www/apk.land/storage/extracted_apks/res/drawable-xxxhdpi-v4/icon.png`

The path is relative to current directory. Buy if you add `/`, the path is absolute from root directory.

Comment: Could you add further explanation as to why this will solve the problem?

Comment: Adding a / won't solve the problem, as leading / are stripped away during Storage::copy()

Comment: It already has a /, as you can see in my code, but it's removed by Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

you have to choose the right disk somthing like this

```
$file2 ='public/'.$page->thumbnail;

$destination = 'public/bundles/ttt.png';

if( Storage::disk('local')->exists($file2)){

      Storage::disk('local')->copy($file2,$destination);
 }
```